# Change image using event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two images: `images/pic1.png` and `images/pic2.png`. And I want to make something like this:
When I click on image(pic1) for the first time it changes its `src` to `images/pic2.png` and then 2nd image is displayed. Next, I click again (2nd time), and my first image is displayed again. And if I click for the third time my 2nd img is displayed again. *And again and again and again.*

Also, I'd like to make it with loop `if(...) ... else{...}`.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<img src="images/pic1.png" id="myImage"/>
```

**JS**

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(img.src != "images/pic2.png"){
    img.src = "images/pic2.png";}
  else{
    img.src = "images/pic1.png";}});
```

I do not know what else to do...

Comment: And I do not know what exactly you're saying the problem might be?

Comment: I don't see a question. What's your problem exactly?

Comment: maybe the problem is relative vs absolute URLs?

Comment: it seems he have a problem with paths, // before your root folder

Comment: it doesnt not works and I don't know why

Comment: @imvain2 maybe it is, how can I solve it?

Comment: try to empty the src first use the below code i tested and its working fine  i used your own code    **var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.addEventListener("click", function(){
console.log(img.src);
  if(img.src != "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic2"){
  console.log("not true");
    img.src = "";
    console.log(img.src);
    img.src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic2";
    }
  else{
    img.src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic1";}});** @Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a working example that shows your code works fine. Unless you are having a problem because of ABSOLUTE VS RELATIVE URLS.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(img.src != "http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000"){
    img.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000";}
  else{
    img.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";}});
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="myImage"/>
```

Comment: thanks! I don't know why it doesn't works here. Can I put this code inside of onload function?

Comment: you can try that. Another test you can try is `console.log(img.src);` at the beginning of the click function to see exactly what its stating is the src. If it has your full url, you will know that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have created this small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yehiaawad/497kz3s5/)

```
<img id='myImg' width='40px' height='40px' src="//i.imgur.com/COFscX6.jpg" />

var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
img.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('changed')) {
    this.src = '//i.imgur.com/COFscX6.jpg';
    this.className = "";
  } else {
    this.className = "changed";
    this.src = "//i.imgur.com/rznnhRq.jpg";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the [`dataset` Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) as id.

That would allow you also to change between more images.

```js
function toggle(){
 img.src='images/pic'+(
  img.dataset['id']=img.dataset['id']++<2?img.dataset['id']:1
 )+'.png';
 img.alt='images/pic'+(img.dataset['id'])+'.png';
}
var img=document.getElementById('myImage');
img.onclick=toggle;
```

```html
<img src="images/pic1.png" data-id="1" id="myImage">
```

in the above case 2 is the maximum and 1 is the first image

`img.dataset['id']=img.dataset['id']++<`**2**`?img.dataset['id']:`**1**

Readable:

```
if( img.dataset['id']<2 ){
 img.dataset['id'] + 1;
}else{
 img.dataset['id'] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HYG you need to empty the src before inserting a new one

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.addEventListener("click", function(){
console.log(img.src);
  if(img.src != "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic2"){
  console.log("not true");
    img.src = "";
    console.log(img.src);
    img.src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic2";
    }
  else{
    img.src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic1";}});
```

```html
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic1" id="myImage"/>
```